# Python Bindings Request for TrajectoryLinearSystem Class

Tags: drake

I would like to use the class *TrajectoryLinearSystem* to create a  time-varying LQR for a free-floating system as I do my own linearization of the trajectory (due to the quaternion state representation of the floating base). However, this class is not yet available in the current python bindings.

Is it possible to request this Python binding via StackOverflow or is it recommended to use GitHub issue tracker instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it's totally fine to open a feature request issue on GitHub.  I've confirmed that the binding is missing, so it's definitely in the realm of "feature request" and not "answering a help question".

I was *going* to say that this would be a great opportunity to open pull request to Drake with the new bindings code that you need (and that's still true), but in this case the inheritance hierarchy of `TrajectoryLinearSystem` is somewhat complicated so the bindings will be slightly more difficult than usual to write.

Comment: I just started compiling Drake from source to start understanding and maybe contributing back (as I've been using it a lot in my research and would like to understand it better and contribute as well). I looked at the pything bindings generation of `TrajectoryAffineSystem` and will use that as a starting point. If I'm succesfull, I'll create a pull request.

Comment: Now implemented as of https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/15397.